# Great Balls are always curveballing

Tags: pokemon-go

For some reason in my game, great balls keep flying off to the right even when I throw them straight. I do not have this problem when using regular pokéballs.

How do I stop great balls from doing this? Or do I just have to throw all of them as a curve ball to work around the problem?

EDIT: This problem seems to have been fixed as of yesterday's update.

Comment: If the problem there after you've restarted?

Comment: @Riley I have restarted many many times. I've been having the problem ever since I first unlocked great balls a few days ago.

Comment: When I looked with a buddy of mine who used great balls they seem to be more sensitive. Making his hold his phone in a weird way to throw the balls.

I don't have great balls myself yet as I'm still level 11 so I can't test it. But I had it happen multiple times with normal Pokeballs.

Comment: I've had this problem - sometimes it happens if you throw the ball too fast. Try press & holding on the ball for a little bit, and then throwing it as you normally would.

Comment: I think this is a "feature" of the game that makes it more difficult as you level up. In my experience it will happen with regular pokeballs as well, it seems to be dictated by how strong the pokemon you're trying to capture is. My trick is that if you manually do a curveball it won't override that.

Comment: I was *just* complaining about this in chat. I'm not spinning the ball, but yet it sparkles yellow and flies off to the right. Super annoying.

Comment: I don't think it's a game feature since it doesn't always happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem seems to happen a lot lately. I have seen it myself an hour ago. Everything I threw right on target turned into a curve ball and went wide. And when I tried to take that curve into account the ball went straight forward and missed as well. Just like you described.

My tip: Yes, always go for a curve ball until it gets fixed. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If it curves to the right, throw it to the left side of the screen !.. It doesnt happen to me as im able to throw great balls normally but i can make them curve itentionnaly by spinning the ball in circles before to throw it

Comment: problem is it changes the direction of the curve - you have to curve it yourself intentionally